# obejct collision detection with tilemap

Tags: javascript, html

Currently working on a platformer just so i can practice some JS, i was able to find alot of videos when i got stuck, but im not sure if its me but i cant find any good videos that help me personally. I have a tile map with one platform

```
 export const tilaMap = () => {
      ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  
      for (let eachRow = 0; eachRow < gridRows; eachRow++) {
          for (let eachCol = 0; eachCol < gridCols; eachCol++) {
              let arrayIndex = eachRow * gridCols + eachCol;
  
              if (collisionblock[arrayIndex] === 6401) {
                  // Draw the black block
                  ctx.fillRect(eachCol * tileW, eachRow * tileH, tileW, tileH);
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Then i have my object that i want collision with

```
export function luke() {
   applyGravity();

   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
 


   let animationState = isJumping ? 'jump' : playerState;

   let animationSpeed = animationSpeeds[playerState]; 
   let position = Math.floor(gameFrame / (staggerFrames / animationSpeed)) % spriteAnimations[animationState].loc.length;

   let frameX = spriteWidth * position;

   let frameY = spriteAnimations[animationState].loc[position].y;

   let renderX = playerX;

   let renderWidth = spriteWidth;

   if (!isFacingRight) {
       ctx.save();
       ctx.scale(-1, 1);
       renderX = -playerX - spriteWidth;
   }
   ctx.drawImage(playerImage, frameX, frameY, spriteWidth, spriteHeight, Math.round(renderX), Math.round(playerY), renderWidth, spriteHeight);
   if (!isFacingRight) {
       ctx.restore();
   }

   gameFrame++;
   requestAnimationFrame(luke);
}
luke();
```

Whats the best method or easiest way to do add collision? Any videos that you recommend that arent on youtube? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

As it’s a tile based game it would probably be easiest to make the tile map function into a class that has an “obstructions” array containing the x,y of items that are collide-able then whenever you are changing an entities position just check that there is nothing in the array with matching coordinates

Edit: I would begin by creating a class for your player controlled character, get used to oop a bit so you can have more reproducible code. Then make something along the lines of `class cmanager { constructor(xdimension, ydimension){ this.width =x;this.height=ydimension; this.map = {}};addItems(update){this.map[objID]=update};moveplayer(direction){let player  ={…this.map[userid]} player.x + direction[0]; player.y + direction[1]; this.map = {…this.map, [player.id]=player}}`  Then just make a method that’s called at end of move to see if any Indexes are overlapping

Comment: That would the best solution you recommend? Im still new to this js and everything gives me headcahes so far lol